# Feature Templates disappear in Arcmap after i remove Feature Class from Table of Contents

Tags: arcmap, file-geodatabase, feature-class, feature-service, template

I am working on some Polygon Data in Arcmap and I am trying to generate about 20 or more feature templates for each Feature Class in the Geodatabase. All my feature classes are in one Feature Dataset and subsequently in a mother Geodatabase. I am able to create feature templates for each one and once i drag the Feature Class into my working area I see all of its associated feature templates in the 'Create Features' pane.

However once, I remove the particular feature class from Table of Contents and drag it back later on into the Working area from Catalog, all my generated feature templates vanish. Even when i restart the arcmap, I return to see all my created feature templates disappear.

Please help me out.